# Apple approved replacement for URLWithString:@"App-prefs:root=FACEBOOK"];

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

My app was rejected from the app store for the following code which is evidently a private API:

```
else if (intVersion>=10.0) {
     NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"App-prefs:root=FACEBOOK"];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
    }
```

What is the best you can do currently (in 2019) to get users as close as possible to the settings for a different app as Apple evidently considers "App-prefs:root" a private API?

Is the best you can do:

```
 NSURL * URL = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
```

This only takes you to the generic settings page.

Comment: Why do you need to open facebook's settings and not its app? Alternatively, encrypt the URL, store it encrypted and at runtime decrypt it..

Comment: How would I decrypt the url at runtime?  Where would this code go?

Comment: There is no way to open preferences other than your own app's preferences. Trying to subvert the approval process can lead to rejection or having your app removed from the store

Comment: It is  legal to open generic preference using URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString], correct?

Comment: encrypting or decrypting the URL does not make any difference because Apple monitors the actual url call, not the url string.